# Running out of space on Linux, copying 12GB of files to a 15GB file system

Tags: linux, ubuntu, filesystems, diskspace

I have two virtual Linux servers, one for development and one in production, a typical setup one would expect.

On the development server I have files that I need to copy to the production server, that amount to 12GB, well according to the "du -h" command. The production server has 15GB free, according to the "df -h" command. However, when trying to copy the files across, the production server ran out of file space!

Whilst I know that both commands round up or down the answer, there should be still over 2GB free at the end, 12.4GB to 14.5GB. Equally, there could be near 4GB as well, 11.5GB to 15.4GB. (For some reason, I get slightly different answers based upon the user, but still enough to fit the files - supposedly.)

Both servers are running 64 bit Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and have the file system set as EXT4.

I'm using SCP to copy the files across, since I don't have enough space to contain a zipped file and its unzipped contents.

So what am I missing?

Comment: Have you checked the size of the swap file on each system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the same with rsync command in terminal. Here is the example of it.

```
$ rsync -a /some/path/to/src/ /other/path/to/dest/
```

Comment: Running the command currently, amended slightly to include the options of -azv to compress and show the output. The infrastructure IT guy has instructed me to rate limit my transfer since it was killing the internet connection for the business (--bwlimit 1000). :)

Comment: I had same problem and used this way. Hope it will work for you in future.

Comment: It copied up in record time and left me with 2.4GB free. God knows why scp made the server run out of drive space, considering it was copying the same files.

Comment: It is not winscp problem. It is the difference between cp and rsync commands. #rsync command have more advantages than copy command. Have a look at [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/43014/copying-a-large-directory-tree-locally-cp-or-rsync)